# jQuery how to append html and remove child nodes with 1 line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My case: I had a container with loading text, text is removed when content is loaded.

My usual approach:

```
$('div#container p.loading').remove()
$("div#container").append(msg)
```

My question, I'm curious if I can do this with one line? So I tried this:

```
$("div#container").append(msg).$('div#container p.loading').remove()
```

But it's not working, I'm just appending the `msg`, the loading text not gone.

Comment: Why one line? Go for 2.

Comment: just CURIOUS, besides I like to keep code as short as possible to make it cleaner and easier to read when it's bulky later (there will be a lot of similar code like this in my design later)

Comment: Maybe then you should try to put all your code in one line?

Comment: yes, unglify and minify all the script after the code is finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div#container').find('p.loading').remove().end().append(msg)
```

or if the loading message is the only content of of container then try

```
$('#container').empty().append(msg)
```

and if `msg` is a string then

```
$('#container').html(msg)
```

Comment: wow that was quick, and it's working, thanks, I'm not familiar with `end`, pretty new to jquery

Comment: I cannot use `html` though, there's something else in the container that must not be removed